# can i trim some modules from lib when i link it in my Makefile?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

for example, i have a lib file named test.a. test.a have three modules: test1.o, test2.o, test3.o. i just need modules test1.o, how can i achieve this in my Makefile.

if anybody knows how to trim the test2.o and test3.o modules, please let me know.thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a static library, only the modules needed will be linked into the executable.

If you use a shared library, the whole of the library will be loaded at runtime, regardless of which functions you use from the library.

Comment: With a shared lib, he will have to create a separate lib containing only those modules he wants to use in the executable.

Comment: take the test.a as a example, do you mean that, when i run the makefile, if my program haven't use test2.o and test3.o, it wil not be linked to the executable? i needn't to handle it in the Makefile?

Comment: @user505423: that's my recollection - you should try it and confirm

Comment: Re shared libraries and "the whole of the library will be loaded"... modern OSes page fault in pages only as they are used, so there's little unnecessary overhead in using a large shared library.  Of course, that applies to executables and the .a issue as well, and it's still nice to ship less code where possible.

Comment: @Tony: yes, i think you are right. i tried it, found that the executable file increase 70 Bytes everytime i add a module into my program. thanks for you help! i get it now.